# CreatePipe не коннектятся

Tags: c, winapi, pipes

Компилирую 2а exe - кладу в одну папку - никак не получается передать в pipe. 
Причем родительский процесс вроде все же что-то пишет в трубу, а сервер - нет

Код клиента:

```
/*
---ИНФО---
Программа была создана Буренковым Игорем в 2018 году

Коды ошибок (X-Y)

X:
    1 - Главный поток
    2 - Поток приветствия
    3 - Поток ввода и интерпретации
    4 - Поток-дерево

Y:
    1 - ошибка памяти



 Проверки Read/Write

 */

// STD  библиотеки и заголовки
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Windows библиотеки и заголовки
#include <windows.h>

// Пределы переменных
#include <limits.h>

// Функции
DWORD WINAPI WelcomeThreadF(LPVOID);
DWORD WINAPI InputThreadF(LPVOID);

// Переменные
PROCESS_INFORMATION  ProcessInfo;         // Инфо о процесс-сервере
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  sa;                  // Секьюрити атрибубны
STARTUPINFO          StartupInfo;         // Стартовые данные о процесс-сервере
bool                 TreeProcSt = false;  // Стартовал ли процесс-с
HANDLE               pipe1Read, pipe1Write,  pipe2Read, pipe2Write; // Трубы
DWORD             out_pipe_b, in_pipe_b; // Число введенных байтов



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//             Функции работы с трубой             //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Печать ошибки
void PrintERROR(unsigned char errorkey){
 switch (errorkey) {

   default:
     // Неизвестная ошибка
     printf("Unknown error!\n");
     printf("Please, contact admin:\n");
     printf("http://natribu.org/\n");
     break;
 }
}

// Пишем символ в трубу
void WriteChar_SlimRG(unsigned char key){
  while (WriteFile(pipe1Write, &key, sizeof(unsigned char), &out_pipe_b, NULL) == 0);
}

// Считываем символ из трубы
unsigned char ReadChar_SlimRG(){
  char key;
  while (ReadFile(pipe1Write, &key, sizeof(unsigned char), &in_pipe_b, NULL) == 0);
  return key;
}

// Пишем INT в трубу
void WriteInt_SlimRG(int key){
  while (WriteFile(pipe1Write, &key, sizeof(int), &out_pipe_b, NULL) == 0);
}

// Считываем INT из трубы
int ReadInt_SlimRG(){
  int key;
  while (ReadFile(pipe1Write, &key, sizeof(int), &in_pipe_b, NULL) == 0);
  return key;
}

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//             Основной поток                       //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    /* ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ */
    char                CPU_cores = 0;      // Кол-во ядер
    SYSTEM_INFO         sysinfo;            // Инфо о системе
    HANDLE              Welcomethread;      // Поток вывода экрана приветствия
    HANDLE              Inputthread;        // Поток обработки данных


    /* НАСТРОЙКИ */

    // Визуальные
    bool Welcome_logo_show = true;    // Выводить приветствие
    bool Styled_console    = true;    // Изменить оформление консоли
    bool CPU_cores_show    = true;    // Выводить на экран количество ядер

    // Отладка
    bool PauseOnExit       = true;    // Выводить Сообщение-Паузу перед выходом


    /* ОСНОВНОЙ ПОТОК */

    // Изменение оформления консоли
    if (Styled_console == true) system("color F1");

    // Вычисляем количество ядер процессора
      GetSystemInfo(&sysinfo);
      CPU_cores = sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
      // Фикс для странных Win ОС
      if ((CPU_cores > 250) || (CPU_cores < 1)) CPU_cores = 1;
      // Вывод даных на экран
      if (CPU_cores_show == true) {
        printf("--------\n");
        printf("Cores: "); printf("%i", CPU_cores);
        printf("\n--------\n");
      }

    // Вывод экрана приветствия
    if (Welcome_logo_show == true)
     Welcomethread = CreateThread(NULL,0,WelcomeThreadF,NULL, 0, NULL);

    // Поток обработки данных
    WaitForSingleObject(Welcomethread, INFINITE);
    Inputthread = CreateThread(NULL,0,InputThreadF,NULL, 0, NULL);

    // Создание процесс-сервера (в главном потоке для ускорения)
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = true;

    ZeroMemory(&ProcessInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION)); // обнуление

    ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));         // обнуление
    StartupInfo.cb = sizeof (STARTUPINFO);

    // Создание труб
    CreatePipe(&pipe1Read, &pipe1Write, &sa, 0);
    CreatePipe(&pipe2Read, &pipe2Write, &sa, 0);

    StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    StartupInfo.hStdInput = pipe1Read;
    StartupInfo.hStdOutput = pipe2Write;

    // Создаем процесс
    if (CreateProcess(
        "TreeSer.exe",      // имя исполняемого модуля
         NULL,              // командная строка
         NULL, NULL,        // SDs
         true,             // дескриптор параметра наследования
         CREATE_NO_WINDOW,  // флажки создания
         NULL,              // новый блок конфигурации
         NULL,              // имя текущего каталога
         &StartupInfo,      // информация предустановки
         &ProcessInfo)      // информация о процессе
         == false){
          printf("Fatal Error: 404\n");
          printf("Error in CreateProcess!\n");
          if (PauseOnExit == true) system("pause");
          return 41;
         }

    // Закрытие бесполезного
    CloseHandle(pipe1Read);
    CloseHandle(pipe2Write);

    // Пайпы созданы
    TreeProcSt = true;

    // Ожидание завершения комманд
    WaitForSingleObject(Inputthread, INFINITE);

    // Закрытие процесс-сервера
    CloseHandle(pipe2Read);
    CloseHandle(pipe1Write);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);

    // Пауза перед выходом
    if (PauseOnExit == true) system("pause");

    return 0;
}

/* ПОТОК ВЫВОДА ПРИВЕТСТВИЯ */
DWORD WINAPI WelcomeThreadF(LPVOID t)
{
    printf("Programm by Igor Burenkov (Alrott SlimRG)\n");
    printf("Variant: 19\n");
    printf("You're welcome!\n");
    printf("Print 'h' for help\n\n");
    return 0;
}

/* ПОТОК ВВОДА */
DWORD WINAPI InputThreadF(LPVOID t)
{
    // Переменные
    bool                    exitkey = false;  // Ключ выхода из потока
    char                    firstkey;         // Первый символ
    HANDLE                  Treethread;       // Поток вывода экрана приветствия
    DWORD                   TreeT_id;         // Идентификатор потока-дерева
    int                     LeafValue;        // Значение листа
    unsigned char           answr;            // Ответ сервера

    // Анализ ввода и выполнение комманд
    while ( TreeProcSt == false) sleep(1);

    while (exitkey == false){
      printf("T>");
      scanf("%c", &firstkey);
      // Если комманда хелп
      if ((firstkey == 'h') || (firstkey == 'H')) {
        // Печать хелп-файла
        system("cls");
        printf("//////\n");
        printf("HELP\n");
        printf("//////\n");

        printf("Commands:\n");
        printf(" S     -> Create new tree\n");
        printf(" T!    -> Terminate tree\n");
        printf(" + 14  -> Add element 14 to tree\n");
        printf(" - 14  -> Delete element 14 from tree\n");
        printf(" x     -> Get max element from tree\n");
        printf(" n     -> Get min element from tree\n");
        printf(" P     -> Print tree\n");
        printf(" e     -> Exit from programm\n");
        printf("Press Enter for exit\n");
      }  else
      // Если команда - создать поток
      if ((firstkey == 's') || (firstkey == 'S')) {
        WriteChar_SlimRG(8); // Печать комманды
        answr = ReadChar_SlimRG(); // Считываем ответ
        if (answr == 1) {
           printf("OK\n");
        } else
        if (answr < 100) {
           PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
        } else {
           printf("Fatal error: ");
           printf("%u", answr);
           printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
           goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
        }
      }  else
      // Если команда - завершить поток
      if ((firstkey == 'T') || (firstkey == 't')) {
        scanf("%c", &firstkey);
        if (firstkey == '!') {
          // Отправка сообщения
          WriteChar_SlimRG(1); // Печать комманды
          answr = ReadChar_SlimRG(); // Считываем ответ
          if (answr == 1) {
            printf("OK\n");
          } else
          if (answr < 100) {
           PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
          } else {
             printf("Critical error: ");
             printf("%u", answr);
             printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
             goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
          }
        }
      } else
      // Добавление элемента
      if (firstkey == '+') {
        scanf("%i", &LeafValue);
        WriteChar_SlimRG(2); // Печать комманды
        answr = ReadChar_SlimRG(); // Считываем ответ
        if (10 < answr < 100) {
          PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
        } else
        if (answr > 100) {
          printf("Critical error: ");
          printf("%u", answr);
          printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
          goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
        } else {
          WriteInt_SlimRG(LeafValue);
          answr = ReadChar_SlimRG(); // Считываем ответ
          if (answr == 1) {
            printf("OK\n");
          } else
          if (answr < 100) {
            PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
          } else {
            printf("Critical error: ");
            printf("%u", answr);
            printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
            goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
          }
        }
      } else
      // Поиск максимального элемента
      if ((firstkey == 'X') || (firstkey == 'x')) {
        WriteChar_SlimRG(3); // Печать комманды
        answr = ReadChar_SlimRG(); // Считываем ответ
        if (10 < answr < 100) {
          PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
        } else
        if (answr > 100) {
          printf("Critical error: ");
          printf("%u", answr);
          printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
          goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
        } else {
          LeafValue = ReadInt_SlimRG();
          answr = ReadChar_SlimRG();
          if (answr == 1) {
            printf("Max Element: ");
            printf("%i", LeafValue);
            printf("\n");
          } else
          if (answr < 100) {
            PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
          } else {
            printf("Critical error: ");
            printf("%u", answr);
            printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
            goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
          }
        }
      } else
      // Поиск минимального элемента
      if ((firstkey == 'N') || (firstkey == 'n')) {
        WriteChar_SlimRG(4); // Печать комманды
        answr = ReadChar_SlimRG(); // Считываем ответ
        if (10 < answr < 100) {
          PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
        } else
        if (answr > 100) {
          printf("Critical error: ");
          printf("%u", answr);
          printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
          goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
        } else {
          LeafValue = ReadInt_SlimRG();
          answr = ReadChar_SlimRG();
          if (answr == 1) {
            printf("Min Element: ");
            printf("%i", LeafValue);
            printf("\n");
          } else
          if (answr < 100) {
            PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
          } else {
            printf("Critical error: ");
            printf("%u", answr);
            printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
            goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
          }
        }
      } else
      // Печать дерева
      if ((firstkey == 'P') || (firstkey == 'p')) {
        WriteChar_SlimRG(5); // Печать комманды
        answr = ReadChar_SlimRG(); // Считываем ответ
        if (10 < answr < 100) {
          PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
        } else
        if (answr > 100) {
          printf("Critical error: ");
          printf("%u", answr);
          printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
          goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
        } else {
          while (ReadChar_SlimRG() == 2){
            for (LeafValue = 0; LeafValue < ReadInt_SlimRG(); LeafValue++) {
              printf("\t");
            }
            printf("%i", ReadInt_SlimRG());
          }
        }
      } else
      // Удаление из дерева
      if (firstkey == '-') {
        scanf("%i", &LeafValue);
        WriteChar_SlimRG(6); // Печать комманды
        answr = ReadChar_SlimRG(); // Считываем ответ
        if (10 < answr < 100) {
          PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
        } else
        if (answr > 100) {
          printf("Critical error: ");
          printf("%u", answr);
          printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
          goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
        } else {
          WriteInt_SlimRG(LeafValue);
          answr = ReadChar_SlimRG(); // Считываем ответ
          if (answr == 1) {
            printf("OK\n");
          } else
          if (answr < 100) {
            PrintERROR(answr); // Предупреждение
          } else {
            printf("Critical error: ");
            printf("%u", answr);
            printf("\n Programm will shutdown...\n");
            goto ERROR_EXITING; // Требуется экстренно выйти!!!!
          }
        }
      } else
      // Выход из программы
      if ((firstkey == 'E') || (firstkey == 'e')) {
        ERROR_EXITING:  // Маркер выхода, т.к. требуется как можно быстрее выйти из программы
        WriteChar_SlimRG(7); // Печать комманды
        exitkey == true;
      }

        // Пропуск строки
      if (firstkey != '\n') {
       while (getchar() != '\n'); // Фикс строки
      }
    }


   return 0;
}
```

Код сервера:

```
// STD  библиотеки и заголовки
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Windows библиотеки и заголовки
#include <windows.h>

// Пределы переменных
#include <limits.h>

// Структура листа дерева
struct leaf { // структура для представления узлов дерева
    int key;                                // Ключ
    struct avlleaf* left;                        // Левый ребенок
    struct avlleaf* right;                       // Правый ребенок
};

// Пременные для pipe
HANDLE inH, outH;
DWORD out_pipe_b, in_pipe_b;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//             Функции работы с трубой             //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Печать ошибки
void PrintERROR(unsigned char errorkey){
 switch (errorkey) {

   default:
     // Неизвестная ошибка
     printf("Unknown error!\n");
     printf("Please, contact admin:\n");
     printf("http://natribu.org/\n");
     break;
 }
}

// Пишем символ в трубу
void WriteChar_SlimRG(unsigned char key){
  while (WriteFile(outH, &key, sizeof(char), &out_pipe_b, NULL) == 0);
}

// Считываем символ из трубы
unsigned char ReadChar_SlimRG(){
  char key;
  while (ReadFile(inH, &key, sizeof(char), &in_pipe_b, NULL) == 0);
  return key;
}

// Пишем INT в трубу
void WriteInt_SlimRG(int key){
  while (WriteFile(outH, &key, sizeof(int), &out_pipe_b, NULL) == 0);
}

// Считываем INT из трубы
int ReadInt_SlimRG(){
  int key;
  while (ReadFile(inH, &key, sizeof(int), &in_pipe_b, NULL) == 0);
  return key;
}

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//             Древесные функции                    //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Удалить дерево
void DeleteTree(struct leaf* tree){
  if (tree->right != NULL) DeleteTree(tree->right);
  if (tree->left  != NULL) DeleteTree(tree->left);
  if (tree != NULL) free(tree);
}

// Добавить элемент в дерево
struct leaf* InsertTree(struct leaf* tree, int leaf){
   if (tree == NULL) {
     tree = malloc(sizeof(struct leaf));
     tree->key = leaf;
     tree->left = NULL;
     tree->right = NULL;
   } else
   if (tree->key <= leaf) {
     tree->right = InsertTree(tree->right, leaf);
   } else tree->left = InsertTree(tree->left, leaf);
   return tree;
}

// Поиск максимальног элемента
int GetMax(struct leaf* tree){
 if (tree->right != NULL) {
    return GetMax(tree->right);
 } else return tree->key;
}

// Поиск минимального элемента
int GetMin(struct leaf* tree){
 if (tree->left != NULL) {
    return GetMax(tree->left);
 } else return tree->key;
}

// Печать дерева
void PrintTree(struct leaf* tree, int lvl){
 if (tree->right != NULL) PrintTree(tree->right, lvl+1);
 WriteChar_SlimRG(2);
 WriteInt_SlimRG(lvl);
 WriteInt_SlimRG(tree->key);
 if (tree->left != NULL) PrintTree(tree->left, lvl+1);
}

// Поиск минимального листа
struct leaf* FindMinL(struct leaf* tree){
 if(tree == NULL) return NULL;
 else if(tree->left == NULL) return tree;
 else return FindMinL(tree->left);
}

// Удаление из дерева
struct leaf* DeleteLeaf(struct leaf* tree, int key){
  struct leaf* temp;
  // Нет совпадений
  if (tree == NULL){
   WriteChar_SlimRG(61);
   return NULL;
  }
  // Поиск элемента
  if (key < tree->key) tree->left = DeleteLeaf(tree->left, key);
  else if (key > tree->key) tree->right = DeleteLeaf(tree->right, key);
  // Иначе элемент найден - обрабатываем случаи
  // Многодетный элемент
  else if((tree->left != NULL) && (tree->right != NULL)){
    temp = FindMinL(tree->right);
    tree->key = temp->key;
    tree->right = DeleteLeaf(tree->right, tree->key);
  }
  // Один ребенок (2й - нулловый)
  else {
    if(tree->left == NULL)    tree = tree->right;
    else if(tree->right == NULL) tree = tree->left;
    WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
  }
  // Итог
  return tree;
}


 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//             Основной поток                       //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() {

  // ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ
  bool              exitkey = false;    // Ключ выхода
  struct leaf*      tree = NULL;        // Дерево
  int               leaf;               // Лист

  // Получение хэндлов пайпов
  inH = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  outH = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

  while (exitkey == false){
    switch (ReadChar_SlimRG()) {
      case (8):
         //Создание дерева
         if (tree == NULL) {
           WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
         } else {
           WriteChar_SlimRG(81);
         }
         break;
      case (1):
         // Завершение дерева
         if (tree == NULL) {
           WriteChar_SlimRG(11);
         } else {
           DeleteTree(tree);
           WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
         }
         break;
      case (2):
         // Добавление элемента
         WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
         leaf = ReadInt_SlimRG();
         tree = InsertTree(tree, leaf);
         WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
         break;
      case (3):
         // Поиск максимального элемента
         WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
         if (tree == NULL) {
           WriteInt_SlimRG(-1);
           WriteChar_SlimRG(31);
         } else
         {
           WriteInt_SlimRG(GetMax(tree));
           WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
         }
         break;
      case (4):
         // Поиск минимального элемента
         WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
         if (tree == NULL) {
           WriteInt_SlimRG(-1);
           WriteChar_SlimRG(41);
         } else
         {
           WriteInt_SlimRG(GetMin(tree));
           WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
         }
         break;
      case (5):
        // Печать дерева
        if (tree == NULL) {
          WriteChar_SlimRG(51);
        } else {
          WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
          PrintTree(tree, 0);
          WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
        }
        break;
      case (6):
        // Удаление из дерева
        if (tree == NULL) {
          WriteChar_SlimRG(61);
        } else {
          WriteChar_SlimRG(1);
          leaf = ReadInt_SlimRG();
          DeleteLeaf(tree, leaf);
        }
        break;
      case (7):
        // Завершение работы
        DeleteTree(tree);
        exitkey == true;
        break;
    }
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Вместо обмена сообщениями по pipe - они тупо виснут.
Не подскажите - в чем ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в выборе труб:

```
WriteFile(pipe1Write, &x, sizeof(double), &writeBytes, NULL);
ReadFile(pipe2Read, &x, sizeof(double), &readBytes, NULL);
```